# AdMob crashes randomly on adView.loadAd(adRequest)

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I know this problem is listed at [Google Group Mobile Ads section](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/jXQW4gwUEDs), but it seems that Google is ignoring this issue.

So I'm trying to avoid the app crash client side with no luck. Surrounding `adView.loadAd(adRequest);` with a `try catch` block didn't work.

The stack trace always the same:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ResourcesManager.appendLibAssetForMainAssetPath(ResourcesManager.java:859)
at android.webkit.WebViewDelegate.addWebViewAssetPath(WebViewDelegate.java:205)
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewDelegateFactory$ProxyDelegate.addWebViewAssetPath(WebViewDelegateFactory.java:194)
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.<init>(WebViewChromium.java:125)
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.createWebView(WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:524)
at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:2320)
at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:2379)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4001)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4118)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:578)
at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:627)
at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:572)
at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:555)
at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:542)
at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:532)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.m.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:244)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.k.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:1220)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.g.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:88)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:106)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.j.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:216)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```